# The jinn was created from fire; but are they still fire?

Tags: jinn, creation

Man was created from clay. Now we are flesh. The jinn was created from fire. But are they still fire?

Someone said they are like in a wind kind of form? Is this true? As in the case of our father Adam? From clay to flesh?

Comment: Humans were created from soil, are we still soil? It's not important, that they still exist in the form, they were created from

Answer (score -2):

It is believed that Jinn were created from a smokeless flame of fire (Quran 55:15). However, this does not mean that they are still made of fire, as the creation of the jinn from fire is understood to be a metaphorical expression of their nature and essence, rather than a literal description of their physical makeup.

According to Islamic belief, the jinn are creatures of a different realm, who are made of a subtler, more refined form of matter than human beings. They are believed to have their own unique characteristics, abilities, and limitations, and are capable of interacting with the human world in various ways.

While the jinn are not considered to be made of literal fire, their association with fire in Islamic tradition is significant in understanding their nature and their relationship to human beings. Fire is often associated with the concept of purification and spiritual transformation in Islamic theology, and this association is reflected in the various stories and legends that feature the jinn in Islamic lore.

Overall, the belief that the jinn were created from fire is an important part of Islamic theology and is understood to signify their unique nature and essence, rather than a literal description of their physical makeup.